# How can I get a sharper corner /more definition right here? Loop Cuts would go all over the object?

Tags: topology

I have made significant progress on my model. Now I have a problem at the top. How can I get a sharper corner/ clearer outline of wedge shape going to the top there (while having control off the sharpness like with edge loops)? Its too rounded (see photos). For all other sharp edges over the object I used loop cuts. But I cant get that technique to work here as edge loops would run vertically all over object and the result didnt look good. Is there a solution? Preferably also with edge loop technique not mark sharp if possible. **Blender file is attached.**

**Object front view:**

[image]

**My Blender Model**

[image]

**Wedge Shape to the top is too rounded off:**

[image]

**Subdivision modifier off:**

[image]

**Side view object**

[image]

**Side view model, front edge of wedge also in side view too rounded:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this topology. You can use the *Shrinkwrap* modifier to make some vertices stick to a correct cylinder shape:

[image]

[image]

If you have a bit of pinching here you can select these vertices, make a custom orientation...

[image]

... keep this custom orientation selected and scale on Z (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>):

[image]

Another solution would be to use a *Shrinkwrap* modifier to make these vertices stick to a cylinder underneath, but the custom orientation solution should work fine. Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Moonboots. Thanks for the reply! I tried your solution. Its not bad but there is some pinching /weird shading going on at the bottom of the "wedge". Is there maybe another solution? Maybe something with mark sharp after all?

Comment: you can use the Shrinkwrap (with these vertices as vertex group) so that these vertices stick to a cylinder underneath, or give these vertices a custom orientation and scale them on Z

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, yes that helps. Sorry for the late reply, I was really busy the last 1.5 weeks. Thanks for your generous help with another question!